# Download climate data in NC format using wget from linux terminal

Tags: linux, url, server, wget, netcdf

I want to download files from this source https://cida.usgs.gov/thredds/ncss/topowx_monthly/dataset.html.

To do so I run the following code in my linux terminal using the NCSS url at the bottom of the page:

```
wget https://cida.usgs.gov/thredds/ncss/topowx_monthly?var=tmax&var=tmin&north=51.1916&west=-125.0000&east=-66.6750&south=24.1166&disableLLSubset=on&disableProjSubset=on&horizStride=1&time_start=1970-01-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&time_end=2016-12-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&timeStride=1
```

I expect to have a netCDF at the end. However, the downloaded file has no extension and is not in netCDF (I tried to read it as such and failed). I don't know in which format it is. How can I solve this ?

Thank you for your help!!

Edit: the problem was that there were special characters in my wget request and that therefore the url needed to be in double quotes, so this works:

```
wget -c "https://cida.usgs.gov/thredds/ncss/topowx_monthly?var=tmax&var=tmin&north=51.1916&west=-125.0000&east=-66.6750&south=24.1166&disableLLSubset=on&disableProjSubset=on&horizStride=1&time_start=1970-01-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&time_end=2016-12-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&timeStride=1"
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about how an API which is not really described in the question works, in detail

Comment: what do you mean? happy to provide more information

Comment: when you say the nc format, do you mean netCDF?  The file doesn't download "properly" but what actually happens?  How do you download it on the server?  Why can't you figure out how to do this yourself?

Comment: Actually I just figured out a way to solve my problem, it was because there were special characters in my URL and didn't to use double quotes around them for wget to perform. Thank you!

Comment: Also - I don't really understand why you gave me a -1. I am not experienced with stack or linux and I am happy to modify the question to take into account your advice

Comment: Sure, the question didn't (in it's original form) include any code, no actual output and didn't mention netCDF.  Questions that are  "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" are also invalid.  There is a whole other site called meta.stackoverflow.com for discussing why these are the policies for here

Comment: Yes, but I modified according to your suggestions and now my question fits all of those requirements no ? :) But anyways since I figured out the answer I can delete it if you prefer. I think it may useful to others, but up to you (:

Comment: I have removed the downvote and close because although your question is "weak" TBH it's no worse than a lot of other stuff on here.  Welcome to Stackoverflow